# How to check previous version app already installed in iOS Device?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

it assumes very simple question but its typical problem for me .

I have a live paid iOS app in App Store . I want to update it in my phone with new Sqlite .
I want test some scenario for that I want installed update from my Xcode in free.
How can i update app installed from App store by Xcode as i have new code of that app.
in my live app there in no USERDEFAULTS to store current version.i can code in new app.

How to delete previously used sqlite and installed new app free if already buy that app.

Thanx for reading.
guide me if any understand it and any idea about it.
Thank in advacnce

http://blog.digidna.net/post/74246563623/how-to-release-a-whole-new-app-and-keep-all-things this was i want

Answer (score 1):

SQLite database file is just a normal file, you do not need any special steps to update it.

Get the file path or URL to the SQLite file , and use 
`NSFileManager`'s method  `removeItemAtPath:error:` or `removeItemAtURL:error:`

Then create the new database the same way you created the old one.

Also check this [link](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1736) if get any problem.

**EDIT :**
    You can delete your old `SQlite`  database file if it's copied in document directory. You CAN NOT delete files from bundle.

Comment: ok its good i already knew about it but i want to detect if that sqlite is available in live app with updating app in XCDOE

Comment: I didn't get your point. You want to update live app with new updated one right?